# dir() will not use its argument

Tags: python, list-comprehension, read-eval-print-loop

I want to write a little function in Python to print every callable method of an Object. In the REPL I would do this to get every list-method:

```
[x for x in dir([]) if '__' not in x]
```

This works fine in the REPL but when I write the same comprehension in a module like:

```
def methods(obj):
    return [x for x in dir(obj) if '__' not in x]
```

I get an error: 
"TypeError: dir() takes no arguments (1 given)."
Where is the problem? Why is it totally fine to write this in the REPL but not in a module?

Comment: Do you have a `dir()` function in that module?

Comment: @AnandSKumar : Wow I am stupid. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably overwrite your native `dir` function.

Try `help(dir)` to see where it comes from.

also notice that `inspect` does exactly what you ask:

```
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(obj, predicate=inspect.ismethod)
```